# Texture appears in Edit Mode but not in Rendered mode

Tags: materials, uv

[image]

Hi,

I've placed a texture on this object and it looks fine in Edit mode but when I switch to rendered mode these black bands appear. It's all assigned as the same material so I'm really unsure as to why this keeps happening.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed a mother loop cut to stop the subsurf at the limits of the object...